# cannot associate image to tkinter label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, photoimage

I am trying to display an image to a tkinter GUI using tkinter.Label() widget. The procedure seems simple and straightforward, but this code doesn't work!

code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Image, ImageTk, sys

filename = 'AP_icon.gif'
im = Image.open(filename) # Image is loaded, because the im.show() works

tkim = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, image = tkim) # Here is the core problem (see text for explanation)
label.image = tkim # This is where we should keep the reference, right?
label.grid (row = 0, column = 0)

tk.Button(root, text = 'quit', command = lambda: sys.exit()).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

When we execute this code, it doesn't compile, giving an error:

```
TclError: image "pyimage9" doesn't exist
```

When I define `label` without its parent `root`, No compilation error occurs, but the GUI does not display any image!

Can anyone identify what could be the issue?

Comment: Your code works for me if I swap the order of the `root = tk.Tk()` and `tkim = ImageTk...` statements.

Comment: Thanks. But I have tried swapping the statements but the same error repeated again. 

Is there any other reason possible?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the above code gives the error you say it does? Usually images internally are numbered starting at zero, but you claim the error mentions "pyimage9" even though your code tries to create a single image.

Comment: Nice that you asked. In fact, the numbering starts at 1 for me. But when I run again (I use ipython in ubuntu 12.04) the number gets updated 2,3, etc. The error I copied is the 9th time I tried to run the similar code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem happens when we attempt to run the above code in Ipython. And it can be solved by changing the line

```
root = tk.Tk() to

root = tk.Toplevel()
```

Comment: That's not really a proper fix because you rely on an imlicit root window created when the first widget is created. You end up with a variable `root` which isn't actually the true root window.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Thanks for the feedback. As of now, I am managing this problem in this way. Is there any better solution or proper fix for this problem?

Comment: i gave a brief answer already: you need to explicitly create the root window before calling any other tkinter commands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the root widget before you call any other tkinter functions. Move the creation of `root` to be before the creation of the image.

Comment: Thanks. But I have tried creating the root at the beginning itself, but the same error repeated again. 

Will there be any other reason possible? Seems like @unutbu above got the code working with the switch.

Answer (score 0):

The general way which I use to display an image in tkinter is:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'name of image.gif')
# If image is stored in the same place as the python code file,
# otherwise you can have the directory of the image file.
label = tk.Label(image = image1)
label.image = image1 # yes can keep a reference - good!
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In the above case it works but you have something like:

```
import Tkinter as tk
image = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'DreamPizzas.gif') #here this is before root = tk.Tk()
root = tk.Tk()
# If image is stored in the same place as the python code file,
# otherwise you can have the directory of the image file.
label = tk.Label(image = image)
label.image = image
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

this gives me a `runtime error: too early to create image.`

but you have said that your error is `image pyimage9` doesn't exist, this is strange because at the top you have set `filename` to 'AP_icon.gif', so you would think that you get a different error as I dont know where `pyimage9` comes from. This makes me think that maybe you are getting the file name incorrect somewhere? You also need to move `root = tk.Tk()` to the top under imports.

Comment: The code you said works for you (the upper one) gave me a blank GUI, possibly because the `label` was defined without the parent `root`. But when I define it with the parent `root`, the same error `TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist` reappears. Even when I define the `image1` before defining the `root`, I get the same error, not the `runtime error` you specified. 
The filename is correct, because as mentioned in the code, `im.show()` did display the image.

Comment: That is very strange, defining the label without the parent `root` is fine, unless there are other tkinter windows running at the same time, are you doing this? maybe to solve this you should make extra windows Toplevel()...?

Comment: Yea, strange, isn't it? I tried `Toplevel(root)` just now. It didn't help. Same error! :(

Comment: I don't know, what IDE are you using?

Comment: python 2.7.3, using IPython 0.12.1, os Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Kernel  to get rid of the error "TclError: image "pyimage9" doesn't exist"

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code as I am able to rectify the same error:

```
window=Tk()
c=Canvas(window,height=2000,width=2000)
p=PhotoImage(file='flower1.gif',master = c)
c.create_image(500,500,image=p)
```