# Can open jpeg files in main window, but can't open it in a second window

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I've been learning how to use the tkinter package and I've come across a problem. After a researching a bit, I found out how to display jpeg images in my window, which I was successfully able to do. However, when I tried to do the exact same thing, but using a button to open a new window and displaying the same jpeg file, I'm getting a lot of errors.

I've also tried keeping reference of my image, as stated [Here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm), but with no sucess.

Code that worked (displaying jpeg image in the main window):

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Test")

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Photo.jpg"))
imglabel = tk.Label(win, image = img).grid(row=1, column=1)

win.mainloop()
```

Code that didn't work (opening the same jpeg file in a second window):

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Test")

def second_win():
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title("Test2")
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Photo.jpg"))
    imglabel = tk.Label(win, image = img).grid(row=1, column=1)

button1 = tk.Button(win, text="Test2", command=second_win, height=5, width=20).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

The second code results in this error:

Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Test/test", line 11, in second_win
    imglabel = tk.Label(win, image = img).grid(row=1, column=1)

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Comment: Also check [cannot associate image to tkinter label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25460418/8321664)

Comment: Will have a look at those, thank heaps!