# The error "pyimage1 doesn't exist" doesn't let me set background image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pyimagej

I want to put the image for background.My code follows..

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import PIL.Image
class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
   
    
    super().__init__()
    self.withdraw()
    
    self.root1 = Tk()  
    self.root1.geometry('800x690')  
    self.root1.title('tkinter')
    img =PIL.Image.open('4.jpg')
    bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)


   # Add image
    label = Label(self.root1, image=bg)
    label.place(x = 0,y = 0)
```

The error is: "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist". How can I set background image?

Comment: post your full code.

Comment: Though I can't pretend I understand WHY, the answer to this post solved the problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460418/cannot-associate-image-to-tkinter-label

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the chaotic way you create your App: you run super.__init__(), which already initializes self as a TK instance, so the root is actually the App() itself. Here is some cleaned-up code that worked for me
(I cleaned up the messy imports too):

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('800x690')
        self.title('tkinter')
        img = Image.open('4.jpg')
        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        # Add image
        label = tk.Label(self, image=bg)
        label.place(x=0, y=0)

        self.mainloop()

a = App()
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to remove `super().__init__()`, so you can use `self.root1`.

Add  `self.root1.mainloop()`

snippet:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk
 
class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    self.root1 = tk.Tk()  
    self.root1.geometry('800x690')  
    self.root1.title('tkinter')
     
    img =Image.open('4.jpg')
    bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

   # Add image
    label = tk.Label(self.root1, image=bg)
    label.place(x = 0,y = 0) 
    self.root1.mainloop()

App()
```