# errror: "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist"

Tags: python, customtkinter

*I keep seeing this error: **_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist***

***My code (important parts):***

```py
        self.see = ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=img.open("./icons/see.ico"))
        self.unsee = ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=img.open("./icons/unsee.ico"))
        self.white = ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=img.open("./icons/White.ico"))
        self.dark = ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=img.open("./icons/Dark.ico"))

        showPass = ctk.CTkButton(
            master=self.loginFrame,
            text="",
            command=lambda:[self.seePass(passwordEntry, showPass)],
            font=("RobotoSlab", 12),
            fg_color='#343638',
            hover_color='#343638',
            corner_radius=50,
            height=10,
            width=10,
            image=self.see
        )
```

Have tried change the img or the way that i declare them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you're creating more than one instance of tkinter, hence the error. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224574/tkinter-create-image-function-error-pyimage1-does-not-exist